# Crop or Trim a Section from a PDF using C# .Net and Ghostscript

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, ghostscript

I am trying to take in a PDF File which has in the center a vector graphic , however it has text and other logos around the page that i do not need.
I need to extract the vector portion of the File only, so far below what i have been able to do is create a CropBox and then convert the cropbox to a bitmap.

This results in extracting the graphic in the center of the page only but the downside is that it is a Bitmap. Once i create the PDF using the cropbox if i open it in windows it shows just what i need, however when i then import it into CorelDraw or Adobe Illustrator it still has all the other data and as i learn the cropbox just hides everything else.

So the question is, how can i go about this with ghostscript or a similar free c# library to turn my crop box PDF section to a new pdf with only that data?

```
 private string CropPDFToBitmap()
    {
        try
        {

            CheckOutputPathExists(); 

            string gsPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.50\bin\gswin32c";
            string argo = $"-o {this.BaseFileLocation}\\cropped\\{RemoveExtension(TargetFileName)}.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -c \"[/CropBox[281 197 531 447]\" -c \" /PAGES pdfmark\" -f {this.BaseFileLocation}\\{RemoveExtension(TargetFileName)}.pdf";
            string ProductionFile = $"{ this.BaseFileLocation}\\bitmaps\\{RemoveExtension(TargetFileName)}.bmp";
            string bitmapArg = $" -dUseCropBox -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=bmp256 -r600 -o {ProductionFile} {this.BaseFileLocation}\\cropped\\{RemoveExtension(TargetFileName)}.pdf";
            // " -dUseCropBox -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=bmp256 -r600 -o C:\\final.bmp  C:\\cropped.pdf"
            //{this.BaseFileLocation}\cropped\{RemoveExtension(TargetFileName)}.pdf

            var cropProcess =  Process.Start(gsPath, argo);
            cropProcess.WaitForExit();
            var bitmapProcess = Process.Start(gsPath, bitmapArg);
            bitmapProcess.WaitForExit();


            return ProductionFile;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed {0}", ex.Message);
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here:

[Can ghostscript.net divide a PDF file to multiple sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708625/can-ghostscript-net-divide-a-pdf-file-to-multiple-sections)

The CropBox in a PDF file is as you noticed, only a directive as to which portions of hte content to render by default. If you actually want to remove the content, then you need to do something like the approach in that answer.